# TFS - Given a personal access token, how can I get my username?

Tags: tfs

I would like to be able to get the User ID that owns a TFS Personal Access Token.

I cannot seem to find any TFS rest web services that do this.

I thought maybe I could use the "get my branches" web service and take the owner of the branch, but unfortunately this does not work because "my branches" are often created by other people.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there isnot a way to get the User Id of the user who creates the PAT by given the PAT.

But if you just want to get your userId you can refer to below rest api.

You can check out [get team members rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get%20team%20members%20with%20extended%20properties?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0). If you are a team member in the team. You can get your userId in the response result.

`GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams/{teamId}/members?api-version=5.0`

See below example in powershell scripts:

```
$url="https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/teams/{teamId}/members?api-version=5.0"
  
$pat='{PAT}'

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
   
$result1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
```

You can get the **TeamId** of your team on the webpage address bar (Project settings-->Teams-->Select the team you are a member of)

You can also create a work item and then call [get work item rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get the workitem details. You will see your userId in the `System.CreatedBy` field of the response result.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0
```

Comment: that's a cool trick - i think that will work as long as i make sure each PAT owner is in a team which i can probably get away with doing